# Trouble while fetching data from API in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, api

I am trying to get data from an API, when I console.log() it , I am getting the data in console, but when I try to get it in my table , I am getting following error:
ERROR Error: Error trying to diff '[object Object]'. Only arrays and iterables are allowed

my ts file

```
CovidPatients:any=[];

  show() {
    this.http.get('https:API-URL').subscribe(responseData=>{
    const data1=JSON.stringify(responseData)
    this.CovidPatients=JSON.parse(data1)  
    console.log(data1);

    })
  }
```

html

```
 <tr *ngFor="let data of CovidPatients">
        <td>{{data.agebracket}}</td> 
         <td>{{data.contractedfromwhichpatientsuspected}}</td>
        <td>{{data.currentstatus}}</td>
<tr>
```

In the API the data is in nested Array , I think that might be the problem:

```
{
    "raw_data": [
        {
            "agebracket": "",
            "contractedfromwhichpatientsuspected": "",
            "currentstatus": "Hospitalized",
            "dateannounced": "10/05/2020",
            "detectedcity": "",
            "detecteddistrict": "",
            "detectedstate": "",
            "entryid": "",
            "gender": "",
            "nationality": "",
            "notes": "",
            "numcases": "2",
            "patientnumber": "37900",
            "source1": "https://twitter.com/ANI/status/1259331384851775488?s=09",
            "source2": "",
            "source3": "",
            "statecode": "RJ",
            "statepatientnumber": "",
            "statuschangedate": "",
            "typeoftransmission": ""
        },
        {
            "agebracket": "",
            "contractedfromwhichpatientsuspected": "",.....................
```

How to display the data in the table.

Comment: Try with `this.CovidPatients=JSON.parse(data1).raw_data` inside `subscribe`

Comment: BTW, don't put your response through `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`, it's a completely unnecessary computation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CovidPatients` is not an array. Change your for loop to this:

`<tr *ngFor="let data of CovidPatients.raw_data">`

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following,

```
show() {
this.http.get('https:API-URL').subscribe(responseData => {
    this.CovidPatients = responseData['raw_data']
    console.log(this.CovidPatients);
})}
```

Then inside your template file, you can iterate through the array using *ngFor structural directive,

```
<tbody *ngFor="let data of CovidPatients">
<tr>
    <td>{{data.agebracket}}</td>
    <td>{{data.contractedfromwhichpatientsuspected}}</td>
    <td>{{data.currentstatus}}</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` both are unrequired if and only if you are getting the JSON object in response. In `*ngFor` you can iterate the array of object if you are not using a `keyvalue` pipe. 
In your JSON object `raw_data` is array so you can try like this

```
<tr *ngFor="let data of CovidPatients.raw_data">
{{data.agebracket}}
.
.
.
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks for  the answer , but if I don't parse it , It won't return the string value, I am getting an object in the console and nothing in view.

Comment: ohh okay so you are getting the string as response, so you have to parse for iterating and one more question in every API you are getting the string as response on only this one?